# MATE desktop popup window class for AutoKey

Tags: autokey, mate-desktop

In MATE desktop in Fedora 28, I have set a shortcut for switching windows using a popup window to Super-j. I've discovered `AutoKey` that allows you to re-map the keys for certain applications/windows. It has a script that tells you what the window class is. But with the popup window, the widnow disappears too fast and the script can't quite grab it as you need to click on the window. Is there a way to get the window class of this popup window? I want to re-bind `left` key to Super-h while the popup is active. Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you refine your question so that it is more clear as to what is this popup window? It's not clear.

Comment: It's the popup that you get when you press ALT-TAB for switching between applications.

Comment: maybe create script which displays IDs for all windows every few seconds and run it all time - and then try to activate popup window. On Linux Mint I tried to use in bash `wmctrl -l` to display all active windows and run it every 1 second using `watch -n 1 wmctrl -l` but it doesn't recognize window activated with ALT-TAB

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have completely switched to i3 window manager, it does all I want.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you've already found another solution, but I thought I'd add an AutoKey solution, too:

```
import time
mouse.wait_for_click(1)
time.sleep(0.2)
winClass = window.get_active_class()
dialog.info_dialog("Window class", "Active window class:\n\n'%s'" % winClass)
```